# Is there any way to detect when the Cancel button it touched on an Apple Pay PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?

Tags: ios, applepay

Apple Pay calls the following delegate whenever a `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` is dismissed for any reason. Is there any way to detect if *just* the **Cancel** button was touched?

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation for paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate/paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:):

> When the user authorizes a payment request, this method is called after the status from the paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:completion: method’s completion block has been shown to the user. When the user cancels without authorizing the payment request, only paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish: is called.

So if

```
paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:completion:
```

Is not called first, then the user tapped the cancel button (or the controller somehow got cancelled otherwise).

Comment: It may be worth suggesting that an invocation flag is stored for the `didAuthorizePayment:` delegate method.